# Setting outlook calendar reminders

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, exchange-server, outlook-2003

Is it possible to use asp.net to create a calendar reminder in outlook?

I am using .NET 3.5 and have MS Outlook 2003.

If this is possible, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only create a calendar reminder in the Outlook that is installed on the server machine. It can't create a reminder in the Outlook of the user that is using your application, because it runs in the sandbox of the browser.
If you want to create the appointment on the server, have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/outlookappointments.aspx

Update:
After you clarified that you are using an Exchange server, you can use the [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633626%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) to [create an Appointment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633661%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx). I haven't used it myself, so I can't help you any further.

Comment: What does it mean to add a reminder on the server?  Does this mean that everyone in the company will end up getting the reminder?

Comment: It means that the reminder is set in the Outlook installed on the server. Who gets the reminder depends on whose login is being used. Based on your comment, I assume, you want to add the reminder to the Outlook installed on the clients PC. That can't be done. What you could do, is to send an appointment via mail to the mail address of the user that uses your application

Comment: So basically, if I have 2 users viewing my webpage, which uses the code in the link you posted above.  if they click on the page, it sets a reminder just for them?  So if user1 clicks the page, it adds a reminder on the server for him only?  And if user 2 clicks the page, it adds a reminder on the server for her only?  Which I assume gets added to their outlook calendars?

Comment: No, you are not understanding it correctly. You were talking about Outlook. The Outlook installed on the server has nothing to do with user1 or user2. Maybe you could solve your problem when you are not just using Outlook but also Exchange...

Comment: You should change your question than. You don't want to interact with Outlook but with the Exchange server.